# data attributes with bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'd like to pass arguments to modal window, such as title.

So I added `data-title`to my link `<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn" data-title="Title goes here">Launch demo modal</a>` and of course when the modal opens I'd like to replace the default title

```
  ...
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
  </div>
  ...
```

My JS goes like this but it doesn't set the proper title.

```
$('.modal-body', "#ModalWindow").html('<%= j render(template: "tasks/new.html.erb") %>');
var Title = $(this).data('title');
$(".modal-title, #ModalWindow").text( Title );
$("#ModalWindow").modal('show');
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is this line:

```
$(".modal-title, #ModalWindow").text( Title );
```

Should be:

```
$(".modal-title", "#ModalWindow").text( Title );
```